# python: elegant way to find the locations inside the radius of provided location using Latitude and Longitude

Tags: python, geolocation, geometry, latitude-longitude, compass-geolocation

I have a set of coordinates (Longitude and Latitude) in decimal notation, and I'm looking for a way to find the coordinates in a circle with variable radius around each location.

[image]

1. Here in above figure you shown clearly red location, first we want do draw a circle around the center point (red location) here we only know the latitude and longitude of that point so my question is, how to draw circle if we only know the latitude and longitude. (in python without using any module or library )
2. Second if draw the circle then how to get all the location that are inside the circle.

Please help me to achieve these two points in Python without any use of library or any other module.

Comment: I don’t know if it possible to plot without modules. Can you clarify it the “no-modules” clause also includes the actual plotting.

Comment: No, I don't need to plot circle, I need only sketch a circle around red location then find all the locations inside the circle (only through python coding No libraries used)

Comment: Is there a difference between plotting and sketching? Correct me if I am wrong by you need a module to visualise.

Comment: I mean that the circle is not visible,

Comment: Then I don’t understand the question to be honest. Perhaps consider rewriting your question.

Comment: my question is that can we make circle if we only know the Latitude and Longitude of a point. if YES then how in python coding...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238111/discussion-between-muhammad-usama-and-kosmos).

Comment: Thank you for the invite. Unfortunately I’ve reached the limit of what I can provide to this question. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You ask a question for drawing etc but you never mentioned on what you plotting on.
It sounds a pretty good usecase for matplotlib.basemap(have done a pretty big project embeded in PyQt5).Starting from what you using to visuallize ,plotting a circle is really easy.Also for your second question finding all points in a circle can be infinite depending on what your coordinates decimal number is , i think you just want to check after if a point belongs in this circle witch is fairly easy too.
I suggest you take a look to basemap or cartropy libraries.
Have fun.